# Decoding a POST value in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a value from a POST array, which has letters and numbers in it automatically substituted with others upon submission, to the exact letters and numbers that are entered into the input field.

I mapped out the combinations - for instance, when you type "123456" in the input field, what you get on POST is "DTHAQO", where "D" stands for "1", "T" stands for "2", and so on. What I'm trying to do is convert that "D" to "1" automatically, and every other letter/number as well, so that the final POST value is the actual value.

What I came up with so far:

```
<?php

function decoder() {
    $decode = $_POST['password'];
    if (strpos($decode,"D") !== false) {
        str_replace("D","1",$decode);
    }
    if (strpos($decode,"T") !== false) {
        str_replace("T","2",$decode);
    }
}

$decoded = decoder();
echo $decoded;

?>
```

However, upon echoing, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function is not returning anything it seems.

Comment: also, you are not storing values returned by `str_replace()`

Comment: Additionally there are better and secure ways to achieve what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I would also consider passing `$_POST['password']` value as an argument to the function. That way the function would become more dynamic and work with different types of input values.

Answer (score 0):

You need the function to return a value in order to use/echo it.

```
<?php

function decoder() {

$decode = $_POST['password'];

if (strpos($decode,"D") !== false) {

   $ret_val = str_replace("D","1",$decode);
   return $ret_val;
}

if (strpos($decode,"T") !== false) {

  $ret_val =  str_replace("T","2",$decode);
  return $ret_val;
}

}

$decoded = decoder();

echo $decoded;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but like Maximus2012 said in the comments, there are better ways to do this

```
$decode = "DTHAQO";//maybe your POST value

function decoder( $stringToDecode ) {
    $decodeArray = array(
        "D" => 1,
        "T" => 2,
        "H" => 3,
        "A" => 4,
        "Q" => 5,
        "O" => 6
    );

    for( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $stringToDecode ); $i++ ) {
        $stringToDecode[$i] = ( isset( $decodeArray[ $stringToDecode[$i] ] ) ) ? $decodeArray[ $stringToDecode[$i] ] : $stringToDecode[$i];
    }

    return $stringToDecode;
}


$decoded = decoder( $decode );

echo $decoded;
```

Answer (score -1):

inside if statements replace

```
str_replace("D","1",$decode);
```

to

```
$decode = str_replace("D","1",$decode);
```

make changes for all similar to `str_replace(letter, number,$decode)` lines

**Update:**
Also, add return statement into functions

Comment: The function still needs to return the value.